# Batch process an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

In PHP I would use `array_chunk` to split up an array then process each chunk. In objective C this doesn't seem so straight forward, is there a cleaner way than something like this?

```
- (void)processTransaction:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSInteger batchCount = (transactions.count - 1) / self.batchSize + 1;

    for (NSInteger batch = 0; batch < batchCount; batch ++) {
        for (NSInteger batchIndex = 0; batchIndex < self.batchSize; batchIndex++) {
            NSInteger index = batch * self.batchSize + batchIndex;
            if (index >= transactions.count) {
                return;
            }
            Transaction *transaction = [transactions objectAtIndex:index];

            // Process
        }
        // Save
    }
    // Done
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `// Save` isn't too complicated I would do

```
- (void)processTransaction:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSInteger batchIndex = 0;
    for (Transaction *transaction in transactions) {
        // Process
        batchIndex++;
        if (batchIndex >= self.batchSize) {
            // Save
            batchIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    if (batchIndex > 0) {
        // Save
    }
    // Done
}
```